# Mechanism to check if works is being done on docker containers

Tags: docker, logging, containers

I have couple of python docker containers, processing data from kafka topics every X seconds.
If the data isn't appearing for i.e. more than 2X time, I should log it somewhere (so I can check which kafka producers to restart - doesn't matter here).

I was thinking about creating some file, where I would keep last message timestamp, and another script/container would check it every X seconds, to find out, if the data should already have appeared. I could check docker logs aswell, if "amount" of logs is increasing (if not, then it means, that no data is appearing).

While those solutions would probably work, I'm not sure, if there isn't already another "ready-made" solution for that issue. Is there something, that I can use to check if the data is being processed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of health check mechanism by putting logs inside: <filename_1>
then the healthcheck would be:

```
if [[ `[ -r <filename_1> ] && cat <filename_1> | wc -l` -ge 1 ]]; then > <filename_1> && echo 0; else echo 1; fi
```

By doing this you check if the file exist then check the number of lines. If greater/equal than 1 you empty it then return 0 .If empty or does not exist you return 1
This will mark your docker as healthy or unheathly.

If you want to restart by itself you can replace `echo 1` by `kill 1` kill 1 will kill process with pid 1 in container and force container exit. Usually the process started by CMD or ENTRYPOINT has pid 1.

```
 [[ `[ -r <filename_1> ] && cat <filename_1> | wc -l` -ge 1 ]] && > <filename_1> && echo 0 || kill 1
```

Don't forget `--restart` always option.